# Can I pass a Class, ID or data-attribute to a DNN Modal using dnnModal.show

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I'm using the following to open a URL in a dnnModal. I'll be showing a consent checkbox on the modal and I need to disable the close button or hide it with CSS.

If I use CSS currently it will hide the close button for all dnnModals which I don't want.

I'd like to pass a custom Class ,ID or data-attribute to the modal if possible. Alternatively, if dnn has a built-in parameter to not show the close button that would be ideal.

```
dnnModal.show('http://SomeURL.com?popUp=true',false,550,950,false);
return false;
```

Outdated Resources

1. https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/138736/using-dnnmodalshow-in-your-modules-and-content
2. https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/511077/scope/posts/dnnmodalshow-url-arguments